# What is the purpose of adding and then immediately removing an event listener?

Tags: javascript, events

I came across the following [on github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/voice-memos/blob/master/src/scripts/controller/AppController.js#L231-L240), which forms part of a Class dedicated to managing the behaviour for a drawer-style side navigation.

```
closeSideNav() {
    this.sideNav.classList.remove('side-nav--visible');
    this.sideNavContent.classList.add('side-nav__content--animatable');
    this.sideNavContent.style.transform = 'translateX(-102%)';

    let onSideNavClose = () => {
        this.sideNav.removeEventListener('transitionend', onSideNavClose);
    }
    this.sideNav.addEventListener('transitionend', onSideNavClose);
}
```

The first three lines of the function need no explanation, but I'm a bit confused by the last three. At first it I thought the `transitionend` event listener was added and then immediately removed - perhaps signalling to another piece of code not shown here - but now I'm really not used to this pattern.

What's the purpose of these lines?

Answer (score 4):

it is *not* immediately removed. Its removed after it triggered *once* . Thats a common pattern for one-time UI actions, e.g. the navigation can just be closed once, a second button press makes no sense and can confuse the running animations etc.

Comment: OK, I see - so the listener is removed once the css animations have finished. But as far as I can tell (indubitably incorrectly), all that occurs once the transitions are complete is the removal of the recently applied listener. I understand that animations require a level of management, but I'm failing to see how this code actually helps.

Comment: @verism it probably has a lot to do with what goes on inside `onSideNavClose`.

Comment: @Pointy Isn't `onSideNavClose` being defined inside the `closeSideNav` function?

Comment: @verism oh, durr; sorry, no coffee yet. Well it's not clear; maybe it's just an example or something. Perhaps you should be asking the *author* of that code, who'd probably know for sure why it's there.